# Datagrid scrollbar with fixed header and scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, datagrid

I have a datagrid in such a way that I set the header not visible and I put a fixed size table as a header instead. Then the datagrid is wrapped in a div which has the attribute "overflow-y:scroll", so I can scroll and view all the datagrid contents as well as the column headers:

[image]

This works fine but its quite ugly. Look the following picture:

[image]

Okey, What I want is put the scrollbar "up arrow" next to the fixed header (a html table) but in such a way that I was still able to see the header while scrolling.

How can I achive this?
thank you.

Comment: One solution is show the scrollbar only and just only when the number of rows are bigger than the grid size: "overflow-y:auto"

Comment: I've tried this with no succed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10068/Fixed-header-in-ASP-NET-DataGrid#_rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is hear. It works great !! 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10068/Fixed-header-in-ASP-NET-DataGrid#_rating

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you have a look on an open-source tiny function i wrote for fixed-table headers: https://github.com/sagivo/fixed-table-header

Comment: Unfortunately this site is down. Do you know any other one?

Comment: @senyortoni - what site? github?

Comment: That you said above https://github.com/sagivo/fixed-table-header. Chrome says Error 111 (net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED)

Comment: It seems is a problem relate with my company security police. I'll check it out when I get home. Thank you.

Comment: you should not work at a place that restrict you from going into github :)